# How to find url of current page in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript

In One of my project here is some scripts. How do I get the URL of the current page to use it in my javascript codes? Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#idea").hideshare({
    link: "current_page_url",
    position: "top"
  });
});
```

Comment: Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be very **late** in your process, well after: Searching the web and looking on MDN. Doing either of those things will find you an answer in seconds.

Comment: And before you *ask* a question, please **search** on SO: [`[javascript] get url of current page`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+get+url+of+current+page).

Comment: Thank you for your suggession. I am new in Software Development. Very Primary learner.